# How to build customized NDK package based on google AOSP source code?

Tags: android-ndk

I have some native libs and want to build them into NDK package, then release the built NDK package to other developers.
Are there any hints about building the customized NDK package?

I can run "make ndk" based on AOSP r81 source code and get the "ndk" folder under the out/soong directory.
but there are only "platform" and "sysroot" subdirectories only under the out/soong/ndk.
furtherly, I cannot find any zip files like the NDK package released from google website.

Are there any suggestions?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend doing it that way. Distributing an entire NDK sounds like overkill for distributing your libraries. I think you (and more importantly, your users) would be better served by a more traditional distribution method.

We do have a tool called [cdep](https://github.com/google/cdep) that can help with this, but the build system integration that it generates isn't idiomatic for CMake, so that may not be your preferred option.

Both CMake and ndk-build have built in mechanisms for importing third-party libraries. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html documents the CMake approach.

ndk-build's mechanisms for this are currently undocumented (I just filed https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/998 to remind myself to fix that). It's fairly straightforward though:

You ship a directory with the following layout:

```
mylib
├── Android.mk
├── include
│   └── mylib
│       └── mylib.h
└── libs
    ├── arm64-v8a
    │   └── libmylib.so
    ├── armeabi-v7a
    │   └── libmylib.so
    ├── x86
    │   └── libmylib.so
    └── x86_64
        └── libmylib.so
```

Your Android.mk would be:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libmylib
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libmylib.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Your users would then install your package into some package directory (for this example, `$PACKAGES`) as `$PACKAGES/mylib`. They would then use this in their Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libfoo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libmylib
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-add-path,$(PACKAGES))
$(call import-module,mylib)
```

If you need to support other build systems, consult the documentation for those.

You're probably interested in subscribing to https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/916. I'm currently working on making distribution of NDK packages easier, it's just still a work in progress.